# Изменения языка в подсказке формы для заполнения в html коде

Tags: html5

Проблема следующая: 
Есть форма для заполнения в html, установка в форме: "required".
При неправильном заполнении поля выдает подсказку на Русском как default.
Вопрос: как менять язык самой подсказки к примеру на English?
Хотелось бы узнать, что конкретно влияет на "язык подсказок" (не языковые ли настройки браузера?) и как можно их менять: через код в html/css/JS? без использования сторонних библиотек. Или же решение лежит исключительно в настройках самого браузера?
[image: Подсказка на Русском, требуется English]

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>Register Form</title>
</head>

<body>
<h1>Register</h1>

  <form>
    <label for="first">First Name</label>
    <input id="first" type="text" name="first" placeholder="John" required="name">

    <label for="last">Last Name</label>
    <input id="last" type="text" name="last" placeholder="Smith" required="name">
  </form>
<!--продолжение...-->
```

Comment: Скажите, вы нашли ответ на свой вопрос? И может занаете, как назначить "placeholder" класс? Меняю язык через JS, но в html нужно назначить класс и не понимаю как это сделать

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ознакомьтесь с этим [кодом](http://jsfiddle.net/zpkKv/2/):

## HTML

```
<form id="form1">
    <input type="text" required />
    <input type="submit">
</form>

<form id="form2">
    <input type="text" required />
    <input type="submit">
</form>
```

## JS

```
$('#form2 input[type=text]').on('change invalid', function() {
    var textfield = $(this).get(0);

    // 'setCustomValidity not only sets the message, but also marks
    // the field as invalid. In order to see whether the field really is
    // invalid, we have to remove the message first
    textfield.setCustomValidity('');

    if (!textfield.validity.valid) {
        textfield.setCustomValidity('Lütfen işaretli yerleri doldurunuz');  
    }
});
```

Comment: Артем, спасибо за ответ. Я видимо не совсем корректно выразил вопрос: хотелось бы узнать, что конкретно влияет на "язык подсказок" (не языковые ли настройки браузера?) и как можно их менять: через код в html/css/JS? без использования сторонних библиотек. Или же решение лежит исключительно в настройках самого браузера?

Comment: @UriShlomy, Скорее всего да, решение в настройках браузера. Туда вы никаким образом не попадёте.